# xamarin ios culture not found by identifier

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, cultureinfo

I'm using xamarin ios including following system library

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Globalization/4.3.0

I'm getting device current language- region from preferred languages and trying to create Culture info from it:

```
 var deviceLang = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];
 var info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(deviceLang);
```

if device returns for example "en-CH" culture info says then he doesn't support such configuration and returns "en-US" culture. if you will search in [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c) you will find such configuration as supported one . Also, to create NSLocale from this identifier is okay:

```
 var loc = new NSLocale("en-CH");
 var dd = loc.Identifier; // returns en-CH
```

Do you have any idea why xamarin.ios doesn't support such culture ? p.s. system.globalization dll is up to date.

Comment: they also doesn't support fa-IR

Comment: I think the document you searched is supported list on Windows Client and Windows Server.

Comment: yes but those languages are supported by microsoft and apple as well, I have no idea why I'm not able to get it in Xamarin

Comment: No, the document doesn't say it is supported in Xamarin. You can open an issue in Github for more information.